# Definite integral involving powers and logarithm

Tags: integration

Does the following definite integral have a closed form solution?
$$
\int_0^1 x^a(1-x^b)^c\ln(1-x)\ dx
$$

Comment: For what it's worth, WolframAlpha can't find one.

Comment: Expand $\ln(1-x)$ into its Taylor series, switch the order of summation and integration, and let $t=x^b$, then employ the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: I have tried that and ended up with the sum
$$-\frac{1}{b}\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{B\left(c+1,\frac{a+n-2}{b}\right)}{n+1}$$ which I lack the ability to simplify further.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer. If $b=1$ this integral is
\begin{align}
\int^1_0x^a(1-x)^c\ln(1-x)dx
\end{align}
Define 
\begin{align}
I(\mu)
&=\int^1_0x^a(1-x)^{\mu+c}dx\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\ \Gamma(\mu+c+1)}{\Gamma(a+c+\mu+2)}
\end{align}
So we have
\begin{align}
I'(\mu)
&=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(\mu+c+1)\ (\psi(\mu+c+1)-\psi(a+c+\mu+2))}{\Gamma(a+c+\mu+2)}
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
\int^1_0x^a(1-x)^c\ln(1-x)dx
&=I'(0)\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(c+1)\ (\psi(c+1)-\psi(a+c+2))}{\Gamma(a+c+2)}
\end{align}